# Call a non-static method in main static method in Java

Tags: java, oop, static

So I am calling a method defined in the main method of the same class. I am referencing the callable method using 'this' keyword. Why cannot I call this non-static method, as shown below, in static main method?

Relevant but a little different question, by choice of design, would it make sense to construct a separate class for implementing logic. Essentially, main class should only have a main method to keep things simple. Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
UniqueChars.java:8: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        System.out.println(this.hasAllUniqueChars(input));
                           ^
1 error




public class UniqueChars {

        boolean hasAllUniqueChars(String input) {
                return false;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String input = "Harry";
                System.out.println(this.hasAllUniqueChars(input));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` is non-static. `this` is an **instance**, and you cannot reference instance variables within a static method since `static` means "one for the entire class."

You should make the `hasAllUniqueChars` method `static` (like `static boolean hasAllUniqueChars(String input)`), so you could do

```
System.out.println(UniqueChars.hasAllUniqueChars(input));
```

Or just (since you're already in the class)

```
System.out.println(hasAllUniqueChars(input));
```

You could also keep it non-static, and do this:

```
UniqueChars uc = new UniqueChars();
System.out.println(uc.hasAllUniqueChars(input));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only use "this" within an instance of an object.

So you either need to make a UniqueChars object, or you need to make hasAllUniqueChars static

Comment: Since when can you only use this within an instance of an object?

Answer (score 2):

Because there's no `this` in a static method, because `this` refers to the current instance (e.g., an instantiated object of that class).

There's no instance for static methods: that's why they're called static methods. They live at the class level, and are not associated with any instance.

You should either (a) create an instance and call the instance method on it, or (b) make the method static and don't bother. If the class doesn't need any instance-specific state, might as well make it static, e.g., a utility method.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
System.out.println(new UniqueChars().hasAllUniqueChars(input));
```

Comment: The way it's written now, yes.  Or, one could remove the `this` keyword and change the signature to `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Method `hasAllUniqueChars` is not static. To make it static you have to put `static` before name `boolean` like `static boolean hasAllUniqueChars`. Static methods don't need instances to be able to call them. So you would call it as `UniqueChars.hasAllUniqueChars()`.
if you don't want method to be static then you would need to create new instance of `UniqueChars` class and then call it. `new UniqueChars().hasAllUniqueChars()` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Either construct an instance of the class that has the main method (possibly in main() itself), and invoke the method on it.

   System.out.println(new UniqueChars().hasAllUniqueChars(input));
2. Or make hasAllUniqueChars() a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object, which is `non-static`. You can't use `non-static` instance to `static` method.